# similarity symmetric block-tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, similar-matrices

I am solving a problem, in the middle of which I reached the following symmetric block-tridiagonal matrix.

‎\begin{bmatrix}‎
0 & B & &0  \\‎
B^T & 0‎ & ‎\ddots‎  \\‎
‎&‎\ddots‎& ‎\ddots‎&B \\‎
 0 ‎& &  B^T & 0
‎\end{bmatrix}‎
Where $B$ is an invertible square matrix and size $0$ is equal to size $B$(matrix B is not necessarily normal). Can I make this matrix similar to the following  tridiagonal block matrix as shown below?

\begin{bmatrix}‎
0 & C & &0  \\‎
C & 0‎ & ‎\ddots‎  \\‎
‎&‎\ddots‎& ‎\ddots‎&C \\‎
 0 ‎& &  C & 0
‎\end{bmatrix}‎

in which size $C$ and $0$ equals $B$.

Comment: If $B$ is normal (i.e. $BB^T = B^TB$), then the answer is yes. However, I don't see any reason that this would hold in the general case.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann matrix B is not necessarily normal.